# html @MEDIA print {}, to hide markup leaves blank space in the print

Tags: javascript, html

i am using java script to print a selected area from in an html page..i used the @MEDIA print { .. to hide all headers, buttons and image from the page. It gets hidden but empty space remains. how do i align the print contents to print from the top of the page..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
@MEDIA print {
    #top_part{
    visibility:hidden;
    }
    #print{
    margin-top: 5px;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top_part">
<button onclick="window.print();">print</button>
hello <br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
test if the printer avoids this content
<br/>
```

print this..

```
</body>
</html>
```

in the code the div top_part contains the buttons and text which i need to hide and it hides but how do i align the printable area from the top corner of the print

Comment: `visibility:hidden;` keeps the elements space. If you don't want that space, use `display:none`.

Comment: You need to close your `<div>` tag.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` deliberately leaves space for the elements (they're invisible, but still present). Try `display: none`.

Comment: thanks display:none is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
@MEDIA print {

#top_part{
display:none;
}
```