# window.print(); while printing it leave blank space at top

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Here is my code :

```
        <body>

        <div class="headerCont noprint">
            <div class="headerHold">
                <div class="logoCont"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="104" height="74" alt="Logo"></div>

                <ul id="navCont">        
                    <li><a href="blogs.html">blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">products</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="experts.php">Expert</a></li>
                    <li><a href="events.html">events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="business.html">Business</a></li>       
                </ul>

                <div class="rightHeadCont">
                    <div class="smIcon fbIcon"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    <div class="smIcon twtIcon"><a href="#"></a></div>

                    <form id="search">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="searchBtn">
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" class="searchInput">            
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="breadCrumbs noprint">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a>></a></li>
            <li><a>Expert</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cl"></div>

    <div class="container">

        <ul class="banner noprint">
          <li><img src="images/headerImg.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/headerImg.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/headerImg.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/headerImg.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="bannerShdw noprint"><img src="images/bannerShdw.jpg" width="100%" height="13"></div>

        <div class="titleCont">
            <h1>Expert</h1>
            <ul id="docIcons">
                <li class="a"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="b"><a href="javascript:window.print()"></a></li>
                <li class="c"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="d"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<?php
        $expertsql = "SELECT * FROM experts WHERE is_active = '1' ";
        $expertex = mysqli_query($db,$expertsql);

        $ispresent = @mysqli_num_rows($expertex);

        if($ispresent > 0)
        {
            while($experts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($expertex))
            {
    ?>    
                 <div class="expertCont">
                    <div class="imgCont">
                        <div class="imgHold">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url;?>thumbnail.php?file=admin/uploads/experts/<?php echo $experts['image'];?>&width=170&height=169&maxw=170&maxh=169">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <h2><?php echo ucwords($experts['name']);?></h2>
                    <?php echo trim($experts['short_description']);?>

                    <div class="readMore">
                        <a href="expert-detail.php?id=<?php echo $experts['id'];?>">Read more ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No Expert Found';
        }
    ?>


</div>
```

CSS :-

```
@media print
{
    .noprint {display:none;}
}
```

The section which I don't want to show while printing is :- `noprint` and I have declared display:none to this class. It also get hidden but it leaves blank page at the top. See the screen shot below :

[image]

How to remove the blank space at the top? I also saw [html @MEDIA print {}, to hide markup leaves blank space in the print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433421/html-media-print-to-hide-markup-leaves-blank-space-in-the-print) but it it not worked for me. Thanks in advance

**EDIT :-**

CSS :-

```
    .headerCont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    background: url(../images/headerBg.jpg) repeat-x bottom center;

.breadCrumbs {
width: 1001px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 38px;
}

.bx-wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 60px;
padding: 0;
}

.bannerShdw {
width: 100%;
height: 13px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your headerCont class has css which enables the class to have any other display value and/or height you might still see that space even when printing. I suggest you use !important:

```
@media print
{
    .noprint {
        display:none !important;
        height:0px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean, .noprint {display:none !important;}

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I tried this it is not working, there is no such css that will display the value

Comment: share you headerCont class decleration with us. and breadCrumbs  while you are at it.

Comment: @Techno What if you set display none to it in the `@media screen {}`, is the space still there? Easier to test it there rather than testing the print all the time.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut see my edit, I have added the css code

Comment: @Joonas .noprint {display:none !important;} is added tomy code it display space at the top

Comment: @Techno Yea, but is it in the `@media screen {}`? Because if it doesn't work in `screen`, it will never work in `print`. By the way, if you can make a http://jsfiddle.net example of the code that's giving you trouble, you have way bigger change of getting precise answer.

Comment: @Joonas sorry I didn't understand, you mean to say I should write like this - `@media screen { @media print
{
    .noprint {
        display:none !important;
        height:0px !important;
    }
}}`

Comment: @Techno No. I basically want you to write the `.noprint { display: none; }` outside of the `@media print {}` so that you can see if the `.noprint` element is hidden when you normally view the website in a browser. This way you don't have to check print preview each time to check wether or not the space is still there. To put it in another way, my suspicion is that the issue is not about print media, but probably about parent content height or something...

Comment: @Joonas I chekced by .noprint { display: none; } and it hide the section

Comment: @Joonas I tried to make the fiddle but print button is not displaying there i don't know why please chk http://jsfiddle.net/Q9w9G/

Comment: @Techno Yes, good. Now you can start debugging it with ease. If you are using Firefox, get firebug if you don't have it. If you have Chrome, you don't need anything extra. Either way, just right-click the empty space in your website and choose `Inspect element`.   That way you can see what element exists in that area and what css it has. ––– It looks like your jsfiddle has no `.noprint` css in there. If it gets too difficult with the jsfiddle, you might wanna try what I wrote above.

Comment: @Techno Yes, there is no `.noprint` css in there what so ever, so thats why the jsfiddle is not exactly working. However I didn't mention that I added the display none css myself and everything seemed to collapse just fine. So it's not very helpful at this point ( probably something else in your code is preventing it from collapsing ). You might wanna inspect the element with developer tools locally, like I instructed above.

Comment: @Joonas I have updated the fiddle and it worked there why ? why it is not wokring on my website? see my updated fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Q9w9G/2/ if you scroll horizantally you will getthe print button there

Comment: @Techno I would have to suspect that it's something else your site that is causing it, something that is not included in that jsfiddle. Maybe there's some javascript that alters the css... Difficult to say really.